# PHP preg_replace is removing emoji characters, I want to keep them

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, emoji

So I have a simple function for converting hashtags, mentions & links to html `<a>` tags, I use this for Twitter and Instagram feeds.

Here's the function:

```
function htmlify($string, $service) {
    if ($service == 'twitter') {
        $search_term = 'http://twitter.com/search?q=';
        $user_link = 'http://www.twitter.com/';
    } else if ($service == 'instagram') {
        $search_term = 'https://instagram.com/explore/tags/';
        $user_link = 'https://instagram.com/';
    }

    if (!$search_term || !$user_link) return false;

    // Conver URLs
    $html_text = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $string);

    // Convert # tags
    $html_text = preg_replace("/#([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$search_term$1\">#$1</a>", $html_text);

    // Convert @ tags
    $html_text = preg_replace("/@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\/\.]*)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$user_link$1\">@$1</a>", $html_text);

    return $html_text;
}
```

This works great but it seems to strip emoji characters from the string. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

**Examples:**

Original:
[image: Original Tweet]

Converted:
[image: Converted Tweet]

Comment: they are displayed as "?", may be something wrong with charset..

Answer (score 1):

Should be using the u (PCRE_UTF8) modifier to work with unicode characters (emoji)
example

```
$html_text = preg_replace("/([\w]+\:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/u", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>", $string);
```

please read the reference for some considerations when using the u modifier
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php